# Spring/H2/Hibernate FORMATDATETIME "unexpected token: 'yyyy.MM.dd'"

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, h2

I have Spring with Hibernate and H2. Everything works just fine, except one of my custom queries:

My Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Match {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO )
    private Long id;

    private Date started;

    private Long time;

    /* Getters and setters here */
}
```

My repository:

```
@Repository
public interface MatchRepository extends CrudRepository<Match, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT IFNULL(sum(m.time), 0) FROM Match m where m.time >= 180000 AND m.time <= 1200000")
    long getPlayingTimeTotal();

    @Query("select count(*) from (select FORMATDATETIME(m.started, 'yyyy.MM.dd') from Match m where m.time >= 180000 AND m.time <= 1200000 GROUP BY FORMATDATETIME(m.started, 'yyyy.MM.dd'))")
    long getNumberOfDays();
}
```

First query for method getPlayingTimeTotal works just fine, but for the second one I get errors:

I get errors:

```
line 1:22: unexpected token: (
```

And also later:

```
line 1:56: unexpected token: 'yyyy.MM.dd'
```

When I check the query in my DB tool (I use [SQuirreL SQL](http://www.squirrelsql.org)) then everything works just fine.

How to fix my query?

Comment: I am afraid H2 does not support subquery.

Comment: try to use `netiveQuery = true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't specify they're native queries, you should use JPQL syntax, eg. `count(m)` instead of `count(*)`.

If you need native SQL, you need to do like follows:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true,
             value = "SELECT IFNULL(sum(m.time), 0) FROM Match m " + 
                     "where m.time >= 180000 AND m.time <= 1200000")
long getPlayingTimeTotal();

@Query(nativeQuery = true, 
             value = "select count(*) from (" + 
                       "select FORMATDATETIME(m.started, 'yyyy.MM.dd') " + 
                       "from Match m where m.time >= 180000 AND m.time <= 1200000 " + 
                       "GROUP BY FORMATDATETIME(m.started, 'yyyy.MM.dd'))")
long getNumberOfDays();
```

Comment: Works just fine. Thank You. I digged Internet and aparently [there are not many datetime functions available in JPQL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/apirefs.1111/e13946/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_datetime). Many examples uses just native function calls. It is actually sad :(

Comment: Well, it's a very HUGE argument, but let me tell you this: there are many ways to achieve what you need. You can use a different field, or you can read the date and format it in Java, you can use Criteria API, or... and don't forget that playing with seconds like that will completely break in case of DST (http://www.baeldung.com/java-daylight-savings). It happened to me years ago, and I've learnt the lesson ;) So the next time (or even this one), take a step back, look at the problem from another angle, and try to avoid pure SQL solutions, especially ones depending on vendor's specific utils

Comment: True. What I want to achieve is the number of distinct days when there were Matches started. I found one solution to format a datetime dayly-based date and then count distinct values on them.

Comment: Unfortunately not as started is day-time based and not only day, e.g.
2018-04-26 08:56:24.872, 2018-04-26 12:17:22.784, 2018-04-27 10:57:40.092

Comment: Got it. Another solution would be to store the date without time in another field. An extra field on the database, which saves you two conversions on that field for *every row* of *every query* ever run. Solutions like this should be used when you can't alter the db, or the code... if you need to filter on the date, the cleanest solution is to have the date in a field. You should have very good reasons *not* to do so, IMHO.